# Customize Kibana visualization

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

From what I've read on the net, **Kibana** does not yet offer any official way to **customize its visualizations**.

But often we'd like to slightly adapt them (without creating new ones from scratch):

- choose the colors of visual elements like auto-generated bars
- change the labels of columns in tables
- add some custom information when hovering over elements
- ...

Is there a generic way to handle this?

More specifically I guess: how to **inject our own JavaScript logic** into the Kibana pages?

Answer (score 0):

Kibana 4 doesn't offer JavaScript injection. However you can customize by own via fork the kibana 4 github code base and Build your kibana packages. I did customization of kibana xAxisLabel & yAxislabel and colors

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately this is not an option for us because we'd like to limit the development and maintenance efforts.